# Transfer apps from one Admob account to other

Tags: android, admob, adsense

Just transferred my android apps to another Google Play Developer account so to get my payouts in Pakistan instead of U.S. I also have Admob account where the payouts only send to U.S. Now I want to receive my payouts in Pakistan therefore I want to transfer my apps to another Admob account with the address of Pakistan. Can I transfer my apps to other account? if not Should I make other ad units in my new account and edit it in my existing apps and then update my apps on Google Play market? will it cause any trouble?
Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There does not appear to be a direct way to transfer ad units. You should contact support team if they can help you with that.

Go with creating new ad units as last option. It will not shift the entire traffic at once to the new account and your earnings will keep getting split between the two accounts till all users update to the app version containing new ad units. This is almost impossible to happen in a short span of time.

You should always use a mediation service. That way you can easily switch between ad units without having to wait for users to update the app just for the ad unit change.

Comment: how can we do that using mediation service? because we access ads in our code using the ad unit id only.