# Transfer AdMob AdUnit to another developer

Tags: admob

Is it possible to transfer AdUnit to another developer? I have a couple of Ad driven apps want to transfer them to someone else without recompiling and resubmitting to play store, so Ad income goes to his account, not mine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not support for your favorite organisation/project

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do that. You can try to contact the admob support and ask if that is possible. [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34382629/transfer-apps-from-one-admob-account-to-other)

What I would personally do:

- Make the person create an admob account with his/her payment info and
- Create a new ad unit.
- Replace the ad unit and publisher id.
- Generate a new APK and publish it.

Comment: Yes, thanks, but as I mentioned, I want to avoid new APK publishing.